# Remove blank rows with different last rows every month

Tags: vba

I would like to remove the blank rows between row 4 all the way down until the last row before the green color cells at the bottom (in this case is row 9). However the last row change every month when there is new outlet or closure of outlet. How do I go about that please? Currently I am modifying the vba code manually every month.

This is my code currently:

```
Sub Raw_Data_Delete_Rows()

  Rows("3:3").Select
  Selection.AutoFilter
  Range("A4:Z9").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=" 
  Range("A4:Z9").Select
  Selection.Delete

End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This deletes all empty rows starting from `4` to `last row - 1`

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub RawDataDeleteRows()
    Dim ur As Range

    Set ur = ActiveSheet.UsedRange

    If ur.Rows.Count > 4 Then
        With ur.Offset(2).Resize(ur.Rows.Count - 2)
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="="
            If .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows.Count > 1 Then
                .Offset(1).Resize(ur.Rows.Count - 4).EntireRow.Delete
            End If
            .AutoFilter
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

---

The Ranges explained

1. Initial Range used for AutoFilter

`ur.Offset(2).Resize(ur.Rows.Count - 2)`

- `.Offset(2)` - moves the Range 2 rows down, from the top (to Row 3)
- `.Resize(ur.Rows.Count - 2)` - resize bottom, 2 rows up, to last used row

---

2. Validation Range for rows to be deleted

`.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows.Count > 1`

- Check that other (visible) rows exit, besides the AutoFilter header

---

3. The Range used to delete empty rows:

`.Offset(1).Resize(ur.Rows.Count - 4).EntireRow.Delete`

- This range is based on the initial AutoFiltered Range above (1)
- `.Offset(1)` - moves the Range 1 row down from Row 3 (Row 4)
- `.Resize(ur.Rows.Count - 4)` - resize bottom, 4 rows up - exclude 3 hdrs & lastrow

---

Note: Determining last row based on `UsedRange` is deliberate, in case last row is empty and green